# Laravel - Как правильно создать запрос к бд, если количество get-запросов точно не определено

Tags: php, laravel

Я реализую поиск по критериям, мне необходимо при определенном get делать `->where('field',$_GET['field']).`
Через костыль, мои догадки:

```
if(isset($_GET['field']))
 $tour = Tours::where('name',$_GET['name'])->get();
if(isset($_GET['another]))
 $tour = $tour->where(...)->get();
```

Comment: orWhere() попробуйте https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = Tours::select();

if ($request->has('param_1')) {
    $query->where('field_1', $request->get('param_1'));
}

if ($request->has('param_2')) {
    $query->where('field_2', $request->get('param_2'));
}

// и так далее - для каждого параметра указываете 
// как он должен влиять на запрос

$tours = $query->get();
```